# Scrape product details from samsclub.com

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, scrape

I'm scraping data from **SamsClub.com** using PHP

```
    $res = file_get_contents('http://www.samsclub.com/sams/bath-towel-apple-gr-100-cotton/prod10450797.ip');
```

I have create function using PHP explode to fetch data.

```
function getData($content,$start,$end){
    $str = explode($start,$content);
    $str = explode($end,$str[1]);
    return $str[0];
}
```

All required data fetched successfully but only one thing is remaining. That is variations of product mean other colors as u can see in snapshot, there are different colors available.

[image]

When we select an other color the **item # & Model # of product also changed** as shown in following snapshot

[image]

I just want to also fetch information like "**item # & model #**" of other colors too.

Waiting for your great response guys.

Comment: Hey, did my answer help you? It took me two hours xD
Were you expecting something different?

Comment: @GiacomoTecyaPigani I need on more thing, I want to save all information in Database too and also need product title. Can you please help me in that. I don't have any experience with "simple_html_dom"

Comment: Ok, I'll help you with grabbing the product title, it's very easy ... but for the database part, you will need to do it yourself. I'll update my answer today

Comment: Done, just add: `$ProductTitle = $html->find('span[itemprop=name]', 0)->plaintext;` after `$html = file_get_html($url);`
It can be wherever, just after you got the html. Also take a look at this document, here you'll find all you need to know ;)
[link](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Comment: @GiacomoTecyaPigani I need your one more help. Currently we are scraping values of different colors and its working fine but there one more option on samsclub to choose size. The solution you provid me is working with sizes too but with sizes options, price also changed. you can see on this link http://www.samsclub.com/sams/suncast-fold-away-pet-carrier-small/prod5600091.ip?searchTerm=24333

I also need prices of other sizes. I tried to find out but my expertise are not enough for this :(

Comment: Ok, I'l take a look. However, if your expertise aren't good enough for this you could always fire them and give me the job. Seriously, if you want to scrape something, send me an email to soldi (.) tecya (@) libero (.) it  so we can talk better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to do this you will need to use a library ([PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)). Just upload simple_html_dom.php somewhere were you are able to include it (in my code, it's in the same folder).

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.samsclub.com/sams/bath-towel-apple-gr-100-cotton/prod10450797.ip';

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html($url);
$colour = array(); $item = array(); $model = array();
$script = $html->find('div[id=variance] script', 0)->innertext;
$script = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $script);
$scripts = explode (";", $script);

$script = $scripts[2];
$id = $scripts[4];
$type = $scripts[5];

$script = str_replace("skuJson.skuVariantJson = $.parseJSON('", "", $script);
$script = str_replace("')", "", $script);

$colours = json_decode($script);

preg_match("/'([a-z0-9]*)'/", $type, $types); $type = $types[1];
preg_match("/'([a-z0-9]*)'/", $id, $ids);     $id   = $ids[1];

$script = $html->find('script', -1)->innertext;
$scripts = explode (";", $script);

$time = $scripts[0];
preg_match('/"([0-9]*)"/', $time, $times);    $time   = $times[1];

foreach ($colours as $key => $value) {
    $url = 'http://www.samsclub.com/sams/shop/product/ajax/ajaxSkuVariant.jsp?skuId='. $value .'&productId='. $id .'&productType='. $type .'&_='. $time;
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    preg_match('/"legacyItemNumber":"([0-9]*)"/', $html, $match); $item[] = $match[1];
    preg_match('/"model":"([a-z-]*)"/i', $html, $match); $model[] = $match[1];
    $colour[] = substr($key, 0, -1);
}

//Print results
echo "<pre>"; print_r($colour); echo "</pre>";
echo "<pre>"; print_r($item);   echo "</pre>";
echo "<pre>"; print_r($model);  echo "</pre>";

?>
```

The only thing you need to change is the $url variable at the beginning. Why all this code, you may ask ... because the data you are looking for isn't on the same page and it's called via ajax every time you click on a colour, so basically we are making a lot of requests (one for each color). This is the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => White
    [1] => Burgundy
    [2] => Apple Green
    [3] => Lilac
    [4] => Chocolate
    [5] => Sage
    [6] => Grey
    [7] => PckBlue
    [8] => Linen
    [9] => null
    [10] => Plum
    [11] => Clay
    [12] => Light Blue
)

Array
(
    [0] => 252368
    [1] => 252505
    [2] => 252414
    [3] => 433076
    [4] => 252389
    [5] => 117268
    [6] => 252438
    [7] => 613317
    [8] => 252382
    [9] => 433083
    [10] => 252541
    [11] => 117175
    [12] => 252400
)

Array
(
    [0] => SAMW-B
    [1] => SAMB-B
    [2] => SAMA-B
    [3] => SAMLC-B
    [4] => SAMCH-B
    [5] => SAMSS-B
    [6] => SAMGR-B
    [7] => SAMPB-B
    [8] => SAMLI-B
    [9] => SAMDR-B
    [10] => SAMP-B
    [11] => SAMTC-B
    [12] => SAMLB-B
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend scraping using .NET and Browser Class. This way you can make the bot click on each color and then grab the required value.

Comment: Thanks @mariobgr But I want it in PHP and I also need to run this on Linux based Apache server.